# Two Reactives Error Invalid Argument to Unary Operator

Tags: r, csv, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to build an app that displays a .csv file in table format. The user can choose with radio buttons one of two ways to display the table. I have defined those two ways with the `filedata()` and `data_ranked_words()` reactives.

To reproduce this error, please first run this code chunk to get a small subset of my data:

```
test = rbind(
  c(0.00000009, 0.00000009, 0.00046605, 0.00015541, 0.00215630),
  c(0.00000016, 0.00137076, 0.00000016, 0.00000016, 0.00000016),
  c(0.00012633, 0.00000014, 0.00000014, 0.00000014, 0.00075729),
  c(0.00000013, 0.00000013, 0.00000013, 0.00000013, 0.00062728)
  )
colnames(test) = c('church', 'appearance', 'restrain', 'parity', 'favor')
rownames(test) = NULL
test = as.data.frame(test)
write.csv(test, 'test.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

You will see that you get an `Error invalid argument to binary operator` as soon as the program launches. Then choose `test.csv` off your filesystem in your working directory and you will see that the error persists while 'Word View' is selected, but the table correctly displays while 'Probability View' is selected.

This app is very simple. The problem occurs in line 66 `temp = matrix(row.names(data)[apply(-data, 2, order)], nrow(data))`. It doesn't like the `-data` within the `apply`. However, try as I might, I have not been able to reproduce this error just working in the R console, outside of shiny. In regular R, this line runs just fine.

What I am trying to do is display two different tables when the user selects the radio buttons. 'Probability View' is the raw table as is, and 'Word View' is the table with some operations on it (lines 61-71). I can't figure this one out!

Here is my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(DT)
library(D3TableFilter)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2) 

# ui.R
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Topic Model App v1.0",
             tabPanel("From CSV",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          # Define what's in the sidebar
                          fileInput("file",
                                    "Choose CSV files from directory",
                                    multiple = TRUE,
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          radioButtons('toggle', 'Choose one:',
                                       list('Word View', 'Probability View'))
                          ),
                        # Define what's in the main panel
                        mainPanel(
                          title = 'Topic Model Viewer',
                          # How wide the main table will be
                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 12, d3tfOutput('data'))
                          )
                        )
                      )
                  )
             )
)


# server.R
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Set up the dataframe for display in the table
  # Define 'filedata()' as the .csv file that is uploaded
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    # Read in .csv file and clean up
    data = read.csv(infile$datapath)
    data = t(data)
    data = as.data.frame(data)
    colnames(data) = paste0(rep('topic', ncol(data)), 1:ncol(data))
    data = format(data, scientific = FALSE)

    data
  })

  #PROBLEM
  # The ranked and ordered csv file
  data_ranked_words <- reactive({
    # Sort each column by probability, and substitute the correct word into that column
    # This will essentially rank each word for each topic
    # This is done by indexing the row names by the order of each column
    data = filedata()
    temp = matrix(row.names(data)[apply(-data, 2, order)], nrow(data))
    temp = as.data.frame(temp)
    colnames(temp) = paste0(rep('topic', ncol(data)), 1:ncol(data))

    temp
  })

  # Create table
  output$data <- renderD3tf({
    tableProps <- list(
      rows_counter = TRUE,
      rows_counter_text = "Rows: ",
      alternate_rows = TRUE
    );

    # Radio buttons
    # The reason why the extensions are in this if() is so that sorting can be
    # activated on Probability View, but not Word View
    if(input$toggle=='Word View'){
      df = data_ranked_words()
      extensions <-  list(
        list( name = "colsVisibility",
              text = 'Hide columns: ',
              enable_tick_all =  TRUE
        ),
        list( name = "filtersVisibility",
              visible_at_start =  FALSE)
      )
    } else if(input$toggle=='Probability View'){
      df = filedata()
      extensions <-  list(
        list(name = "sort"),  #this enables/disables sorting
        list( name = "colsVisibility",
              text = 'Hide columns: ',
              enable_tick_all =  TRUE
        ),
        list( name = "filtersVisibility",
              visible_at_start =  FALSE)
      )
    }

    if(is.null(filedata())){
    } else{
      d3tf(df,
           tableProps = tableProps,
           extensions = extensions,
           showRowNames = TRUE,
           tableStyle = "table table-bordered")
    }
  })



  # This line will end the R session when the Shiny app is closed
  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
})

# Run app in browser
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of problems are interacting here to make things difficult to diagnose:

- It is running through and trying to execute before the data is defined. The "modern" way to avoid that is to use a `req(input$file)` - which is now inserted in the `filedata` reactive. Note that will break the entire chain from executing until `input$file` is defined in the shiny ui.
- The `data = format(data, scientific = FALSE)` is converting your columns to vectors of type "AsIs", which the unitary minus command does not know how to operate on. It is commented out of `filedata()` now.
- To get that functionality of suppressing the scientific notation back, the was moved to right after where `df` is created by `filedata()` before it is displayed in `d3tf`.
- Note: I found it interesting that `options` with `scipen` did not work here. Not sure why that is the case, but this `AsIs` class does the trick.

Here is the adjusted code:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(DT)
library(D3TableFilter)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2) 

# ui.R
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Topic Model App v1.0",
             tabPanel("From CSV",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          # Define what's in the sidebar
                          fileInput("file",
                                    "Choose CSV files from directory",
                                    multiple = TRUE,
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          radioButtons('toggle', 'Choose one:',
                                       list('Word View', 'Probability View'))
                        ),
                        # Define what's in the main panel
                        mainPanel(
                          title = 'Topic Model Viewer',
                          # How wide the main table will be
                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 12, d3tfOutput('data'))
                          )
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)


# server.R
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Set up the dataframe for display in the table
  # Define 'filedata()' as the .csv file that is uploaded
  filedata <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    infile <- input$file
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    # Read in .csv file and clean up
    data = read.csv(infile$datapath)
    data = t(data)
    data = as.data.frame(data)
    colnames(data) = paste0(rep('topic', ncol(data)), 1:ncol(data))
#    data = format(data, scientific = FALSE)

    data
  })

  #PROBLEM
  # The ranked and ordered csv file
  data_ranked_words <- reactive({
    # Sort each column by probability, and substitute the correct word into that column
    # This will essentially rank each word for each topic
    # This is done by indexing the row names by the order of each column
    data = filedata()
    temp = matrix(row.names(data)[apply(-data, 2, order)], nrow(data))
    temp = as.data.frame(temp)
    colnames(temp) = paste0(rep('topic', ncol(data)), 1:ncol(data))

    temp
  })

  # Create table
  output$data <- renderD3tf({
    tableProps <- list(
      rows_counter = TRUE,
      rows_counter_text = "Rows: ",
      alternate_rows = TRUE
    );

    # Radio buttons
    # The reason why the extensions are in this if() is so that sorting can be
    # activated on Probability View, but not Word View
    if(input$toggle=='Word View'){
      df = data_ranked_words()
      extensions <-  list(
        list( name = "colsVisibility",
               text = 'Hide columns: ',
              enable_tick_all =  TRUE
        ),
        list( name = "filtersVisibility",
              visible_at_start =  FALSE)
      )
    } else if(input$toggle=='Probability View'){
      df = filedata()
      df = format(df, scientific = FALSE)
      extensions <-  list(
        list(name = "sort"),  #this enables/disables sorting
        list( name = "colsVisibility",
              text = 'Hide columns: ',
              enable_tick_all =  TRUE
        ),
        list( name = "filtersVisibility",
              visible_at_start =  FALSE)
      )
    }

    if(is.null(filedata())){
    } else{
      d3tf(df,
           tableProps = tableProps,
           extensions = extensions,
           showRowNames = TRUE,
           tableStyle = "table table-bordered")
    }
  })



  # This line will end the R session when the Shiny app is closed
  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
})

# Run app in browser
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

And here is a screen shot of it running:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your help. The issue was I didn't know about `req(input$file)`. I was wondering what the way to stop the reactive from being triggered was, and this is it! Going to be very helpful for my future Shiny programming. Very strange about the scientific notation, I was having issues with that even when I used `options()` to turn it off, so I just commented it out. But this solution is ideal!